# integral of f(x)/dx

Tags: calculus, integration

(I'm new to calculus, please don't attack me if I get something wrong)

So I was playing around with integrals and integral notation, and I thought back to Riemann sums, and how in ∫(f)dx, the dx is a representation of the infinitely small width of a rectangle multiplied by the rectangle's height at f(x).

From there I thought back to the product integral and asked if it is possible to integrate a function by dividing by dx instead of multiplying by it. So for example, ∫(f/dx). Is there a name for this? And what would it look like visually?

Comment: Assuming that $\mathrm{d}x$ represents the infinitesimal width of a rectangle, what possible meaning could $1/\mathrm{d}x$ have?

Comment: There was an answer, like when you click “post an answer” for an MSE question, for “$\int\frac1{dx}$” [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4145975/can-the-integral-int-edx-be-solved?noredirect=1)

Comment: @TymaGaidash I would be very careful about asserting that there is "an answer" there.  If you read the answers carefully, you will note that they all basically start out with "This is nonsense, but if you are willing to do some nonsensical stuff, I suppose that you could write..."  There is *heavy* hedging there.

Comment: Since you are beginning Calculus, when performing integration, think of $dx$ as "Integrate the expression with respect to the variable x" so $\int \:xydx=\frac{yx^2}{2}+C$.

Answer (score 2):

Let's consider a standard definite integral expressed as a Riemann sum.

$$\int_a^b f(x) dx = \lim_{\Delta x \to 0} \sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor \frac{b-a}{\Delta x} \rfloor - 1} f(a + k\Delta x) \Delta x$$

Note that the multiplication by $dx$ in the integral directly translates into a multiplication by $\Delta x$ in the summation.

Now, consider your hypothetical example with *division* by $dx$ instead of multiplication.  This is nonstandard notation, but let's try to make sense out of it.

$$I := \int_a^b \frac{f(x)}{dx}$$
$$= \lim_{\Delta x \to 0} \sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor \frac{b-a}{\Delta x} \rfloor - 1} \frac{f(a + k\Delta x)}{\Delta x}$$
$$= \lim_{\Delta x \to 0} \frac{1}{\Delta x} \sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor \frac{b-a}{\Delta x} \rfloor - 1} f(a + k\Delta x)$$

Let's rewrite this to focus on the number of sub-intervals, $N := \frac{b - a}{\Delta x}$, from which $\Delta x = \frac{b - a}{N}$.

$$I = \lim_{N \to \infty} \frac{N}{b - a} \sum_{k=0}^{N - 1} f(a + \frac{k(b-a)}{N})$$

It can be shown that on any interval on which either $f(x) > 0$ or $f(x) < 0$, the pseudo-integral summation diverges to $\pm\infty$.  Not very useful.

---

The thing that makes the traditional Riemann sum definition work nicely is that the multiplication by $\Delta x$ in the summed values cancels out the *division* by $\Delta x$ in computing the length of the list of numbers to be summed.  So $\Delta x$ just determines *which* values of $f$ get included in the sum, and does not itself contribute much to the final sum.

If you try to do other operations with $\Delta x$ than multiplying by it, then the $\Delta x$ itself will skew the summation value.  You either wind up with a sum that converges to zero, as in $\lim_{\Delta x \to 0} \sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor \frac{b-a}{\Delta x} \rfloor - 1} f(a + k\Delta x) (\Delta x)^2$, or one that diverges to infinity, as in the previous example.

Comment: When you let $m=\min f$, you're implicitly assuming that $m>0$ - otherwise the lower bound is either $0$ or $-\infty$, neither of which give you much information. Even if $m=0$, as long as $f$ is not identically zero the partial sums are strictly increasing and so must diverge. Definitely outside the scope of OP's question, but I do wonder if you could make sense of that sum for (say) a very wildly oscillating $f$ which takes both positive and negative values.

Comment: @csch2: Good point.  I was assuming a *proper* integral, which not only requires $[a, b]$ to be bounded, but $f$ to be bounded on that interval.  It may be possible to construct an unbounded $f$ for which the pseudo-integral converges.

Comment: Wait what does min mean?